function executing after intended
My function starLine will retrive coordinates from firebase and store it in global array startLineCoords. Then another function is called that will check if this array has elemnts.
When I run the code, the check happens first and then startLine executes
OnCreate:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        polygon = new PolyList<>(30);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.StartLine();

        Log.d("Test6970",String.valueOf(pointCounter));


StartLine:
private void StartLine(){
        startLineReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Start Line");
        try{
            startLineReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
                        String latRef=i+"/lat";
                        String lngRef=i+"/lng";
                        @Nullable double latitude = snapshot.child(latRef).getValue(Double.class);
                        @Nullable double longitude = snapshot.child(lngRef).getValue(Double.class);
                        startLineCoord[i]=new Point(latitude,longitude);
//                        Log.d("Trial1",String.valueOf(startLineCoord[i].lat));
//                        Log.d("Trial1",String.valueOf(startLineCoord[i].lng));
                        incrementer();
                    }
                    Log.d("Test6969",String.valueOf(pointCounter));
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }catch (Error e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lap module error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

LogCat:
2024-04-11 10:03:42.145 16344-16344 Test6970                com.example.mrt_app_client           D  0
2024-04-11 10:03:43.226 16344-16344 Test6969                com.example.mrt_app_client           D  4
2024-04-11 10:04:44.560 16744-16744 Test6970                com.example.mrt_app_client           D  0
2024-04-11 10:04:45.749 16744-16744 Test6969                com.example.mrt_app_client           D  4

I tried creating a setter to change the gloabl variable. it doesn't work

It seems like startLineReference is local inside the method startLine and it should be a global member of the class it is in. This way, it won't lose it's reference when the method finishes running.
